# how to set json format to html5 attribute "data-settings"

Tags: javascript, json, html

This's the div concerned:

```
<div id="map" class="map" data-settings="map-settings.json"></div>
```

map-settings.json :

```
{
"mapZoom": 15,
"markerAddress": "881 7th Ave New York",
"offsetX": 100,
"offsetY": 10,
"markerImagePath": "assets/img/marker-21x32.png",
"markerLatLng": [
    40.7652577,
    -73.9798788
]}
```

I want to put the JSON file inside the "data-settings" attribute i tried this :

```
<div id="map" class="map" data-settings='{
"mapZoom": 15,
"markerAddress": "881 7th Ave New York",
"offsetX": 100,
"offsetY": 10,
"markerImagePath": "assets/img/marker-21x32.png",
"markerLatLng": [
    40.7652577,
    -73.9798788
]}'></div>
```

But dosen't work !

Any help ?

Comment: Could you provide code where you access it?

Comment: The `data-*` attributes can be Strings only. Check [w3 schools docs](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp). You can save the JSON string in the `data-settings` attribute and do a `JSON.parse()` wherever you use them.

Comment: @VivekPradhan Thanks you are right! but I tried this `$.getJSON(JSON.parse($(this).data('settings')), successCallback).fail(failCallback);` is there something wrong ?

Comment: @MassiIssar, why do you need `getJSON`? You are not getting a `json` file from a remote server. Just do `var a = JSON.parse($(this).data('settings');` wherever and the variable `a` should have that `json` object. Just make sure when you are doing `$(this).data('settings')`, that it points to the correct node. :)

Comment: Yeaah it works now, i dont need to getJSON :p $(this).data('settings') returns an object and I pass it to my function, Thank u so mush @VivekPradhan for your help

Answer (score 0):

It does; All you have to do is to access it like

```
var  myMap = document.getElementById("map"),
mySettings = JSON.parse(myMap.dataset.settings);
```

Comment: it works without parsing it to JSON, I only did this : `$(this).data('settings');` returns object

Comment: @Massi Issar i guess jQuery uses JSON.parse() under the hood. What i show is pure JS. We need to parse "from" JSON into JS object.